# SQL INNER JOIN + SELECT NOT EXIST ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have three tables:

Table One: Users

Table Two: Roles

Table Three: UserInRoles

- Users

---

```
UserID                                |  FullName
--------------------------------------------------
07DCEE4A-6598-42E1-95C6-0390FF8BB534  | John Doe
```

- Roles

---

```
RoleID
---------------------------------------
E5C46F8E-EE6A-4052-AABA-08184E5F0158
```

- UserInRoles

---

```
UserID                               | RoleID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
07DCEE4A-6598-42E1-95C6-0390FF8BB534 | E5C46F8E-EE6A-4052-AABA-08184E5F0158
```

I need to Select all `UsersID` who's not in table `UserInRoles` from table `Users`

I tryed :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.UserId, Users.FullName 
FROM Users 
INNER JOIN UserInRoles 
ON Users.UserId <> UserInRoles.UserId
```

Comment: Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Select all UsersID who's not in table UserInRoles from table Users, simply use `not in`

```
select distinct * from users where userid not in
(select userid from UserInroles)
```

Comment: @PekiPeki please accept the answer if it works for you

Answer (score 4):

Think `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1 from UserInRules ur where u.UserId = ur.UserId);
```

Comment: @PekiPeki . . . For the record, this is more performant than Ven's answer.